# How can I read a real double array from a text file in Visual Basic?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, input, file-io

I think this must be quite simple, but I am new to Visual Basic. What I want to do is to read a set of real numbers from a text file and create a double array with them in my VB program.

I have found on several places the ReadAllText method, but I need the array to be double. Other codes I have found are too complicated for what I consider a simple task. For example, in Fortran, you just write a subroutine to read it with the OPEN statement, a FOR cycle, and that's all.

Is there a simple way for doing this?

Comment: You can use `File.ReadAllLines()` and then use `double.TryParse()` to turn each value into a `double` in a new collection.

Comment: What you describe in FORTRAN is basically what you do in VB too. As suggested by @David, you can call `ReadAllLines` to get a `String` array from the file. You can then loop through that using a `For Each` loop and convert each `String` to a `Double`. Alternatively, you can create a `StreamReader` and read the file line by line in a `Do` or `While` loop and convert as you read.  The most concise option would be to throw some LINQ at it, e.g. `Dim numbers = File.ReadLines(filePath).Where(Function(s) Double.TryParse(s, Nothing)).Select(Function(s) Double.Parse(s)).ToArray()`.

Comment: In the above code, you can remove the `Where` call if you are confident that all the data is valid, but that is not really ever a valid assumption for real data. The `Where` call means that invalid data is ignored. If you want to notify the user on invalid data then you probably should use a loop.

Comment: Thanks, guys, you're awesome! I couldn't make work the `For Each` loop, an error about the out of bounds index of the matrix arose every time I tried to run the code. I used a regular `For` loop instead, is there any issue with that?

Comment: If you want direct correspondence between indexes in two arrays then a `For` loop is the correct option. If there is a chance that some of the text data will be invalid then you should use a `For Each` loop (a `For` loop would also work but is less appropriate) and then add those values that do convert to a `List(Of Double)`, which you can convert to an array at the end if you want to.  Actually, I'll write an answer that illustrates both options.

Comment: @MSalmer: `"is there any issue with that?"` - With code you're not showing us?  And behavior you're not describing to us?  There's no way for us to know.  If you're just asking where *loops* work in Visual Basic then yes, yes they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to end with an array and start by calling `File.ReadAllLines`, here's how you might do it if you're sure that all data is valid:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim upperBound = lines.GetUpperBound(0)
Dim numbers(upperBound) As Double

For i = 0 To upperBound
    numbers(i) = Convert.ToDouble(lines(i))
Next
```

Here's an even simpler option:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim numbers = Array.ConvertAll(lines, Function(s) Convert.ToDouble(s))
```

If some of the data might not be valid then this is a better option:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim numberList As New List(Of Double)

For Each line In lines
    Dim number As Double

    If Double.TryParse(line, number) Then
        numberList.Add(number)
    End If
Next

Dim numbers = numberList.ToArray()
```

You can also use something like the LINQ option I provided earlier:

```
Dim lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
Dim numbers = lines.Where(Function(s) Double.TryParse(s, Nothing)).
                    Select(Function(s) Double.Parse(s)).
                    ToArray()
```

That last option is a little inefficient because it parses each number twice but it's succinct and that inefficiency is not a big deal if the amount of data is small.